# UCHAR* to std::string

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the WinAPI for one of the first times, and i have a function that returns a UCHAR*, but i need it as a std:string, because when i try printing it as a UCHAR* but when i did that it prints a lot of gibberish.  There must be some easy way to fix this problem.  I Googled this but i could not find anything.  I don't even know what a UCHAR* is although it seems to act as some kind of string.  I heard that it is a pointer to an unsigned string but i am not quite sure what that means.

Comment: I would guess `UCHAR` means `unsigned char`. But it's not a standard definition. Since you got the UCHAR from somewhere surely you have some idea what it means.

Comment: it is from the chemistry part of the BATTERY_INFORMATION struct http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What makes you confident that even after you've converted your UCHAR* to std::string that it still won't print as gibberish? Maybe it contains gibberish? To help more I think we'd need to see a little more code. In particular the function itself, and how you attempted to print the string.

Comment: It's not `UCHAR*`, it is `UCHAR[4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the members of that structure are not null terminated:

```
std::string chemistry(battery_info.Chemistry, battery_info.Chemistry + 4);
```

Will get you the behavior your want without having to do a `memcpy`;

Comment: Except that if it is null terminated it will add a null into your string that you probably didn't want. The docs say it *may* not be null terminated.

Comment: `battery_info.Chemistry + strnlen(battery_info.Chemistry, 4)` maybe.

Comment: @john In that case you would just end up with an extra null terminator that you could strip out easy enough (if you really wanted your `size` function to return exactly the length of the non-'\0' characters).

Comment: @JonathanPotter That would work, but is non-standard.

Comment: @ZacHowland: And `BATTERY_INFORMATION` is standard? :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
char temp[5];
memcpy(temp, battery_info.Chemistry, 4);
temp[4] = '\0'; // add nul terminator
std::string s = temp; // convert to string
```

Because your source data does not necessarily have the usual nul terminator, I've copied the data to a temporary char array, added a nul terminator to make sure, then converted to a std::string.